# Angular - How to reuse a component in a different level?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Imagine we have this component structure:

```
app1
-- app1.component.html
-- app1.component.ts

parent1
    parent2
        app2
        -- app2.component.html
        -- app2.component.ts
```

How could I reuse the `app2` component in the `app1`? For example, reuse a table (both HTML and logic on typescript) instead of copy and paste code.

I have searched for solutions like `ng-template`, but failed. Also, call the tag didn't work as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the tag didn't work inside app1 I assume that you are importing app2 component inside another module. If we want to use component over multiple modules you need to import app2 ONLY in shared module then import that module to modules where you want to have that component.

Make sure to export that component inside shared module.

Comment: I would like to add that you would also need to make sure you export the component in the shared module that is being imported. I think creating a shared module would be the way to go especially if you want a component to be used in multiple modules.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use componentFactoryResolver https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
For example you want to use ThirdComponent inside FirstComponent

```
//HTML
<section #firstComp></section>

//TS
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ThirdComponent } from '../third/third.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.scss']
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('firstComp',{read: ViewContainerRef}) firstComp: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {    

  }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ThirdComponent);
  const componentRef = this.firstComp.createComponent<ThirdComponent>(componentFactory);
}
}
```